# How to get network type(2G/3G/Wi-Fi) in Symbian C++?

Tags: c++, networking, symbian

In Symbian C++ application I need to get current network type (2G/3G/Wi-Fi). How can I do it by code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the RConnectionMonitor API, [see here for the sample code](http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/Determine_the_bearer_type_using_RConnectionMonitor_API), and [see here for the available bearer types (TConnMonBearerType)](http://www.developer.nokia.com/document/Cpp_Developers_Library/GUID-759FBC7F-5384-4487-8457-A8D4B76F6AA6/html/rconnmon_8h-source.html)